Inductive from CoInductive?
It is possible to represent CoInductive using parts that are Inductive. As a simple example,
CoInductive stream A :=
| SCons : A -> stream A -> stream A
. 
Arguments SCons {A}.

CoInductive streq {A} : stream A -> stream A -> Prop :=
| SRefl : forall h ta tb, streq ta tb -> streq (SCons h ta) (SCons h tb)
.

Definition shead {A} (s : stream A) := match s with
| SCons h _ => h
end.
    
Definition stail {A} (s : stream A) := match s with
| SCons _ t => t
end.

Definition stream_unfold {A} (s : stream A) : s = SCons (shead s) (stail s).
  destruct s; apply eq_refl.
Defined.

Definition stream_idx {A} := fix loop (s : stream A) n := match n with
| 0 => shead s  
| S n0 => loop (stail s) n0
end.

Definition stream_from_fn {A} :=
  cofix s (f : nat -> A) := SCons (f 0) (s (fun n => f (S n))).

Definition fneq {A B} (f g : A -> B) := forall a, f a = g a.

Theorem stream_from_fn_from_stream {A} (s : stream A) : streq s (stream_from_fn (stream_idx s)).
  revert s; cofix seq; intros.
  destruct s.
  rewrite (stream_unfold (stream_from_fn _)).
  apply SRefl, seq.
Qed.
  
Theorem fn_from_stream_from_fn {A} (f : nat -> A) : fneq f (stream_idx (stream_from_fn f)).
  intros n; revert f; induction n; intros; [ apply eq_refl | ].
  apply (IHn (fun n => f (S n))).
Qed.

So, we can convert between nat -> A and stream A and they are isomorphic. In a sense, we are representing the CoInductive with a function based on the Inductive nat.
My question is: Is the reverse possible? Can an Inductive be built using CoInductive? For example, imagine you had Coq only with the CoInductive statement, but not Inductive statement, nor did you do the same by making equivalent Axioms. (Other axioms are okay.) How far could you build?
(Forwarded from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78345073/ )

This is a theoretical question about an impossibility of construction, which means that a negative answer is only possible if we carefully describe what is and isn't available. Saying "imagine Coq without Inductive" is too lax for this purpose. A reasonable formulation would be: consider Martin-Löf type theory with ∏, ∑, Id (and nothing else) and the coinductive type of streams (over any type). Does this theory define the type of naturals? There is still a question of what are the precise rules for streams. It sounds like a potentially very difficult question.

Also note that you did not really show that streams and functions are identical, only extensionally equal (fneq instead of =). This is a well-known phenomenon.

Correct, they're extensionally equal.  As a side question, do you know that that theorem is called?
Right, I realize I only gave an example and not an entire formal system.  That's because this is a general question to find out what's already known.  I don't know if there is a simple construction. So, can it be built directly?  Is it known not to be possible?  Are there axioms that one typically adds to make it possible or not?

If you only allow Pi, Sigma, Id, and coinductive records (which includes streams but not "potentially infinite lists"), then your type theory has a model in which every type is either empty or a singleton, implying that you will not be able to define the type of naturals.
If you allow arbitrary Coq coinductive definitions, then the question seems more difficult: you can already use those to define finite sets and disjoint sums...

You should not expect to be able to pull a similar trick with inductives as you have with coinductives.
Inductives are initial algebras of strictly positive polynomial endofunctors, while coinductives are, I believe, terminal coalgebras of strictly positive polynomial endofunctors.
The hom functor is right adjoint to product-with, and right adjoints are closely tied to terminal morphisms.  So it is not too surprising that coinductive types (universally defined by a "mapping in" / terminal-ish property) can be constructed straightforwardly in terms of functions, which are also defined by a "mapping in" / terminal-ish universal property.
There's no reason to expect to be able to somehow combine two things defined via terminal-ish universal properties, though, and get an initial-ish universal property.
(Perhaps someone with more category-theory knowledge than I can turn this into an actual proof.)

There is, however, the Church encoding of inductive types: take the non-dependent eliminator, drop all instances of the inductive type, and use that type to define the inductive.
We don't get the dependent eliminator unless we internalize parametricity, but if we do axiomatize the free theorem from relational parametricity and play fast and loose with universes via universe polymorphism, then we can prove an isomorphism, e.g., between nat and the Church encoding of nat:
From Coq Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.
Scheme Minimality for nat Sort Type.
Check nat_rect_nodep. (* nat_rect_nodep : forall P : Type, P -> (nat -> P -> P) -> nat -> P *)
Set Universe Polymorphism.
Definition NAT := forall P : Type, P -> ((*nat -> *) P -> P) -> (* nat -> *) P.
Definition ZERO : NAT := fun P z s => z.
Definition SUCC : NAT -> NAT := fun n P z s => s (n P z s).
Definition fwd : NAT -> nat := fun n => n (nat:Type) O S.
Definition bwd : nat -> NAT := nat_rect_nodep NAT ZERO (fun _ => SUCC).
Lemma fwd_bwd : forall n, fwd (bwd n) = n.
Proof.
  cbv [fwd].
  induction n as [|n IHn]; [ reflexivity | ].
  cbn; cbv [SUCC]; rewrite IHn; reflexivity.
Qed.
(* from https://free-theorems.nomeata.de/ *)
Axiom NAT_parametricity
  : forall f : NAT,
  forall t1 t2 : Type, forall g : t1 -> t2,
  forall x : t1,
  forall p : t1 -> t1,
   forall q : t2 -> t2,
     (forall y : t1, g (p y) = q (g y))
     -> (g (f t1 x p) = f t2 (g x) q).
Lemma bwd_fwd : forall n, bwd (fwd n) = n.
Proof.
  intro n.
  cbv [fwd].
  extensionality P.
  extensionality z.
  extensionality s.
  etransitivity;
    [ refine (@NAT_parametricity n (nat:Type) _ (fun nv => bwd nv P z s) O S _ _)
    | cbv beta; reflexivity ].
  cbn; cbv [SUCC].
  reflexivity.
Qed.

For completeness, we can also define the eliminator:
Definition PRED : NAT -> NAT := fun n P z s => n ((P -> P) -> P) (fun _ => z) (fun g h => h (g s)) (fun x => x).
Definition NAT_rect_nodep : forall P : Type, P -> (NAT -> P -> P) -> NAT -> P
  := fun P z s n => n (NAT -> P) (fun _ => z) (fun rn n => s (PRED n) (rn (PRED n))) n.
Lemma PRED_SUCC : forall n, PRED (SUCC n) = n.
Proof.
  cbv; intros.
  extensionality P.
  extensionality z.
  extensionality s.
  erewrite NAT_parametricity with (g:=fun v => v s) by reflexivity.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
Lemma fwd_PRED : forall n, fwd (PRED n) = pred (fwd n).
Proof.
  intro n; evar (v : nat); transitivity v; [ rewrite <- (bwd_fwd n); subst v; reflexivity | ]; subst v.
  destruct (fwd n) as [|n']; [ reflexivity | ].
  cbn [Nat.pred].
  cbv [bwd] in *; cbn [nat_rect_nodep].
  rewrite PRED_SUCC.
  apply fwd_bwd.
Qed.
Lemma NAT_rect_nodep_ZERO : forall P z s, NAT_rect_nodep P z s ZERO = z.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
Lemma NAT_rect_nodep_SUCC : forall P z s n, NAT_rect_nodep P z s (SUCC n) = s n (NAT_rect_nodep P z s n).
Proof.
  cbv [NAT_rect_nodep].
  intros.
  unfold SUCC at 1.
  f_equal.
  { etransitivity; [ | apply PRED_SUCC ].
    reflexivity. }
  { f_equal.
    etransitivity; [ | apply PRED_SUCC ].
    reflexivity. }
Qed.


Ah, to state your argument more explicitly, since functions and coinduction act the same way, by using a Church Encoding, it's a function, thus coinductive, but acts inductively the same as the corresponding natural number.

I'm not sure whether what you wrote captures the essence of what I wrote.  I'm particular, I'm not making any connection between Church encoding and coinductives.  And it's possible that parametricity here is what allows you to take a terminal thing (function) and turn it into an initial thing (inductive type)

I played with it for a bit.  But, as you said, I'm not sure how to account for that the type in the Church encoding is parameterized.  The examples that I tried have a structure that makes the index correspond to a specific inductive type.  I'm not sure how it could work for any type.

@scubed Can you elaborate a bit more?  Or if your question is just "does this particular type/type family have a Church encoding, and, if so, what is it?", maybe it's worth asking that as a separate question?  Or are you asking what the parametricity axiom should be for some other particular inductive type?
